# Hibernate - Java pagination - Out of memory exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the following piece of code to get results from DB as result set is huge.

Is it the correct way doing? 
I am running in to Out of memory exception and I suspect it is because of this.

```
// div is set to 10,000
// i have calculated how many times i need do it using a count query
// and that value is being used in iteration variable

Query bigQ=session.createSQLQuery(bigQuery);

for(int i=0;i<iteration;i++)    
{
    bigQ.setFetchSize(div);                         
    bigQ.setMaxResults(i*div);

    List<Object[]> result=bigQ.list();

    // now i am using the result to get the values 
    for(Object[] a:result)
    {
        // rest of operations
    }
}
```

Note:

1. I have set enough Xms and -Xmx in the `jboss run.conf`.
2. I am not able use scrollable set as the postgre driver is not supporting it.
3. I can not use `createQuery` as in that case hibernate is generating lots of queries, so i am using a big join query, along with `createSQLQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks strange - the correct way to paginate results would be this:

```
bigQ.setFirstResult(i * div);
bigQ.setMaxResults(div);
```

Also make sure that your session cache doesn't grow - if your query returns only scalar values (not entities) it shouldn't be a problem, but if you load some entities in `// rest of operations`, it can.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..how do i make sure that session cache does not grow ?

Comment: Thanks again for giving the hint of clearing the session cache. I am able to recover from the out of memory error after using session.evict()

Answer (score 0):

Use offset and limit...  http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm